# Is it possible to stop Icefaces from appending -dis to a disabled component's style class?

Tags: stylesheet, icefaces

I have the following code (only relevant attributes included):

`<ice:inputText styleClass="myClass" />`

renders as

`<input class="myClass" />`

which is perfectly fine, but

`<ice:inputText styleClass="myClass" disabled="true" />`

renders as

`<input class="myClass-dis" disabled="true" />`

so the original style class is no longer applied.

Now, of course I could change my CSS to accomodate for that, but I have several different classes for differently styled input fields, which would all need to then have their own -dis version. This is especially annoying since the disabled style is the same for all of them and the normal CSS way is perfectly suited to handle this: simply combine classes to add the desired look to whatever the standard style is.

So, is there a way to stop IceFaces from automatically affixing my style classes (e.g. like prepending form-IDs can be controlled)?